# Testing the common trends assumption

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am reading [Cusato and Castillo (2023)](https://publications.iadb.org/en/access-credit-and-expansion-broadband-internet-peru), an IDB Working paper on the effect of broadband internet expansion and access to credit in Peru.

The authors use a staggered difference in difference approach - as expected, they run tests to validate that the common trends assumptions holds.

Their analysis is at the Centro Poblado (CP) level, the smallest administrative unit in Peru.

They run two types of tests :

- The first test regresses, with specific regressions for each year, a variety of CP baseline caracteristics on a dummy taking a value of 1 on the year of arrival of broadband and 0 if not (see figure 3 page 12). I understand the motivation behind this : if there are significant differences in baseline characteristics, then we may assume that the common trends assumption may not hold.
- The second test I have more difficulty understanding (figure 4, page 16). Here, the authors plot the results of their main specification (ie, vs the counterfactual of those CPs that never have access to broadbands). Looking at time periods before the introduction of broadband (*t-3* to *t*), they claim that the lack of significance of the coefficients plotted means a lack of pre-trends. However, I understand that these coefficients would reflect a difference in levels (which we would not really care about in a diff-in-diff). What am I getting wrong ? Wouldn't the most interesting have been to plot the evolution of a baseline year (e.g., *t-1* - the year before the treatment - as I understand is often done in the literature) ? Or does lack of statistical significance between treated / untreated across years necessarily mean that there is no common trend ? And that the sudden appeareance of a statistically significant parameter mean that there is a violation of common trends (as for the # of loans per relationship) ?

Thank you !